# Apache2 + FCGI + PHP5 not creating sockets / pools

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, fastcgi

I have a pretty vanilla setup with Apache2, FastCGI setup as DSO and serving PHP through an external CGI script that sets the max children / serves the request to PHP.

The issue is FastCGI doesn't appear to be creating the PHP sockets / pooling them so each request calls the php-cgi binary, then dies off .. effectively making the reason I want to use FastCGI moot.

The only configuration directives I have are:

`AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php`

`Action php5-fastcgi /cgi-bin/fcgi.cgi`

`FastCgiIpcDir /usr/local/apache2/fastcgi`

The `dyanmic/` directory is getting created as anticipated, but there are no sockets in there. Permissions are indeed correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Also to clarify a little further - I know I could technically spawn the sockets manually / use the ExternalFCGIServer directive, though this is not ideal for me.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I figured out the issue. In the `cgi-bin/` directory options I added:

`SetHandler fastcgi-script`

Apparently it didn't do that by default / I missed it somehow - hence why FCGI wasn't managing the threads / workers.

Hopefully this helps someone down the road!